# How to display data inside a div in html taken from json through javascript using ul li

Tags: php, javascript, json

Json file is

```
<?php

    $chapter_1 = array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'SolarOn Elearning Demo Video.', 'total_sections' => 2,
    'sections' => array (array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'This video explains SolarOn service offerings in brief.', 'video' => 'solaron.flv' ),
        array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'section-2.', 'video' => "vid3.flv" ) ) );
    $chapter_2 = array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Introduction to Social.', 'total_sections' => 3,
    'sections' => array (array ('id' => 1, 'name' => 'section-1.', 'video' => 'vid5.flv' ),
        array ('id' => 2, 'name' => 'section-2.', 'video' => 'vid1.flv' ),
        array ('id' => 3, 'name' => 'section-3.', 'video' => 'vid2.flv' ) ) );

    $array_data = array ('chapters' => array ($chapter_1, $chapter_2 ));

    $json_data = json_encode( $array_data );

    print $json_data;    
?>
```

Now I have to show the all categories and section name like tree inside a div in html using java script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Ajax for this. if you are, you can simply return the html list to javascript and use innerHTML to put the list inside a div. The catch here is that there is no need to return json since you can return html except in cases where you are getting the json from an external site.

Comment: I agree returning the HTML from PHP is an option - But he might want to be able to access the data associated with the HTML, if that's the case JSON data returned would be better.